# Ionic Blank Screen in Browser and on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I got the task to check out an Ionic-Application and the Source-Code. I have a compiled .apk File which works perfect on Android. Now I checked out the project. It is written with Typescript and AngularJS, everything seems normal. I went into the Ionic folder and did `ionic add platform android` and then created a valid apk-File. However it doesn't work i only get a blank screen. The file size of my apk and the one which works is quite the same.

In Webstorm I tried running it in the Browser, by doing run-configuration and then Run Browser. There I also get a blank page. The top URL points to the right starting point. In the Developer Tools everything seems normal. I see all the Script Sources and Console-Messages. The only thing is, that he says he is missing the Keyboard plugin, but I guess, that's not really relevant.

So what are my options? There is no one of the Developers left in our company, so no one we can ask, how they compiled the App. There is a package.json, where there are cordova-plugins defined even the keyboard. There is also a gulp-file which seems to only compile the Sass and do something with Bower.

I can't publish the whole project, also because of legal issues, but what's my best option? I never have done something with Ionic, so it's hard to locate the Error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My solution was to check out the code in a folder, go to that folder and then run

> npm install -g ionic

If I didn't do that - I'd get no end of errors when trying to get it to work.